# How to match a word from column and compare with other column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have the below dataframe

```
Text                                Keywords       Type
It’s a roll-on tube                 roll-on        ball
It is barrel                        barrel         barr
An unknown shape                                   others
it’s a assembly                     assembly       assembly
it’s a sealing assembly             assembly       factory
its a roll-on double                roll-on        factory
```

I have first found out the keywords, and based on the keyword and its corresponding type, it should true or false

For example,
when the keyword is roll-on , the type should be "ball" or "others"
when the keyword is barrel, the type should be "barr" or "others"

Output

```
Text                                Keywords       Type         Result
It’s a roll-on tube                 roll-on        ball         True
It is barrel                        barrel         barr         True
An unknown shape                                   others       False
it’s a assembly                     assembly       assembly     True
it’s a sealing assembly             assembly       factory      True
its a roll-on double                roll-on        factory      False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the rules, then you can code them up as you would usually do.

For e.g.

`df['Keywords'] == "roll-on" & (df['Type'] == "ball" | df['Type'] == "others")` => `df['Result'] = True`

If you have too many rules and associations to manually code, you could consider using a look-up table + merge procedure. Here you would store all the rules and associations as a table (i.e. this would include `Keywords`, `Type`, and `Result`), and merge `Result` back on to your original dataframe (`by` Keywords and Type).

Comment: Its showing invalid syntax, because of "=>" this. What is the right syntax for using in pandas dataframe?

Comment: That "code" wasn't intended to be used... Just as an example of the logic you would need. You would probably need some `if` and `elif` statements, as well as correcting the conditional data selection and correcting the assignment of values.

Comment: @anaghas have you put a reproducible code in your question to make it easier for other to give you the code ?!